# Keras: split to train and test after adding noise is not working

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, autoencoder

I built a denoising autoencoder for training and testing I had to split dataset(image) to train set and test set. If I split before adding noise its working but if I split after adding nosing its not working. I need to split after adding noise. what is the problem here

```
train_size = int(images.shape[0]*0.8)
x_train = images[0:train_size]
x_test = images[train_size:]

x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (len(x_train), 64, 64, 1)) 
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (len(x_test), 64, 64, 1))  

noise_factor = 0.3
x_train_noisy = x_train + noise_factor * np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=2.0, size=x_train.shape) 
x_test_noisy = x_test + noise_factor * np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=2.0, size=x_test.shape) 

x_train_noisy = np.clip(x_train_noisy, 0., 1.)
x_test_noisy = np.clip(x_test_noisy, 0., 1.)
```

This is working

```
noisy_set = images[0:].astype('float32') / 255.
noisy_set = np.reshape(noisy_set, (len(noisy_set), 64, 64, 1)) 

noise_factor = 0.3
noisy_set = noisy_set + noise_factor * np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=2.0, size=noisy_set.shape) 


noisy_set = np.clip(noisy_set, 0., 1.)

train_size = int(images.shape[0]*0.8)
x_train = images[0:train_size]
x_train_noisy = noisy_set[0:train_size]
x_test = images[train_size:]
x_test_noisy = noisy_set[train_size:]
```

This is not working

Comment: You have to be more explicit on what you mean "not working".

Comment: Is thee an error? Is so, could you include the full traceback?